# After hit Enter in a text box, redirect to newtab url - bypass Firefox pop-up block

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

Here is my script:

```
jQuery('#textfield').keydown(function (e){
    var text = document.getElementById('textfield').value;
        if(e.keyCode == 13){

            //document.getElementById('btntextfield').click();
            //window.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
            //window.open("https://www.w3schools.com");
            //setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('btntextfield').click();}, 3 * 1000);
            alert("tsdks");
        }
});
```

html:

```
<input id="textfield" class="form-control" placeholder="search term..." type="text">
<a id="btntextfield" class="btn btn-carousel btn-lg" href=#" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Search</a>
```

So I am trying to - after typing and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> in text box to redirect a new page the user. I tried two methods:

1. after typing in text box and hit enter to redirect direct to new page
2. after typing in text box to fire the "btntextfield" button

but every time its blocked by Firefox ...

Please help

Comment: You need to have pop-ups enabled. Not sure about Firefox, but in Chrome, it is disabled by default.

Comment: This (https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/pop-blocker-settings-exceptions-troubleshooting) explains how popups work in Firefox - the user has to manually enable it. " Pop-up blocking is turned on by default, so you don't have to worry about enabling it to prevent pop-ups from appearing in Firefox."

Comment: So pop-up blocking for me is enabled, like in default mode, but I want to baypass it > when I redirect, for the mozilla firefox user do not show that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `keydown` you can use `keypress` to bypass the popup block. You can check this Pen for reference:

https://codepen.io/ropilz/pen/qjoXNM

```js
jQuery('#textfield')
  .keypress(function (e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
      document.getElementById('btntextfield').click();
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="textfield" class="form-control" placeholder="search term..." type="text">
<a id="btntextfield" class="btn btn-carousel btn-lg" href=#" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Search</a>
```